# How can I troubleshoot "Attach to Process" issues in MonoDevelop?

Tags: debugging, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm using MonoDevelop 2.8.2 with the latest Unity 3.5 release. I can no longer "Attach to Process" to the Unity Editor - how can I troubleshoot this? I can still launch Unity directly from MonoDevelop and debug (breakpoints, etc.), but this is cumbersome and unstable. So, any tips on how to troubleshoot this issue? How exactly does MonoDevelop figure out what processes it can attach to?

Comment: You cannot attach to a running process with monodevelop 2.6? onwards. That feature didn't work reliably and I think required the hard debugger (mdb). MD 2.8 only supports GDB and the soft debugger.

Comment: Works without problems here. I use the latest version provided with Unity 3.5.0f5 mostly Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Unity preferences - there's an option that determines whether MonoDevelop can attach to the Unity editor. Maybe it's been turned off somehow?